# If app in review status for more than 1 week, it will be rejected. Is this true?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Someone said if the app in review status for more than 1 week, it will be rejected. My app is in review status for 2 weeks. Will it be approved? How long it may take?

This app is quite important to our company. I'm worried about it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been lied to badly.

Apple usually reviews apps for **weeks**. Don't be afraid.

(Still, it can be rejected, but really, that doesn't at all depend on the time for which your app is being reviewed...)

Answer (score 4):

Apple can take anywhere from hours to weeks to review things. There's not much you can do but wait it out, just be patient and don't panic. Unless you did something really crazy in your app, you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it can take up to 2 weeks. We've had apps in the store for over a week before they were approved.

Answer (score 1):

No, it sometimes takes up to a week for an app to get approved. Just make sure you followed their guidelines and it should be approved fine.